# $\int \frac{2x + 3}{x^2 + 1} dx$ using complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms

I was trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int \frac{2x + 3}{x^2 + 1} dx$$

So, the first thing that I thought was to use partial fractions, but then I noticed that $x^2 + 1$ doesn't have any roots so it's not possible to twite it as $(x - a)(x - b)$. But then I noticed that $x^2 + 1$ does have roots: $i$ and $-i$ so I did the following:

$$\int \frac{2x + 3}{x^2 + 1} dx=\int \frac{2x + 3}{(x+i)(x-i)} dx$$ and after doing all the partial fractions I got:

$$\left(1+\frac{3}{2}i\right)\int\frac{1}{x + i}dx + \left(1-\frac{3}{2}i\right)\int\frac{1}{x -i}dx$$

And this is equal to:

$$\left(1+\frac{3}{2}i\right)\ln(x + i) + \left(1-\frac{3}{2}i\right)\ln(x - i) + C$$

The thing is that now I'm stuck with all these $i$s in the final function and this must be a real function. I plotted this function in my calculation and for all $x$ it has a real output. So, how can I manipulate this expression in order to cancel out the $i$s?

Comment: Use $\ln z = \ln |z| +i\arg z$.

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms) for $\frac 32 i \ln \frac {x+i}{x-i}= 3 \arctan x$

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach:  Break up the integral into two integrals:
$$\int \frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx + \int \frac{3}{x^2+1} dx$$
The first can be solved by a $u$ substitution, and the second can be solved if you know the derivative of $\arctan x$.

Comment: +1. Why partial fraction decomposition into complex numbers when you can break up the integral by the numerator?

Comment: Often times, more complicated solutions provide excellent insight into another area of mathematics. Why partial fraction decomposition into complex numbers? Why not...? Just because you have one proof doesn't make another proof invalid. It provides a great insight into complex numbers, and the way that partial fractions can be used. In general, 2 proofs are better than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ so $\ln(x^2+1)=\ln(x+i)+\ln(x-i)$

Answer (score 1):

First write it as $$\ln(x^2 +1) +\frac{3}{2} i (\ln(x+i) -\ln(x-i) ) +C$$ Use $\ln z =\ln|z| +i\arg z $ for the two natural logs.
First, for $x\ge 0$,
$$\arg (x+i) = \tan^{-1} \frac 1x \\ \arg (x-i) =-\tan^{-1} \frac 1x $$ and so you get $$\ln(x^2 +1)-3 \tan^{-1} \frac 1x + C $$

While for $x\lt 0$, $$\arg (x+i) =\pi + \tan^{-1} \frac 1x \\ \arg(x-i) = -\pi -\tan^{-1} \frac 1x $$ and you get $$\ln(x^2 +1) -3\pi -3\tan^{-1} \frac 1x + C =\ln(x^2 +1) -3\tan^{-1} \frac 1x + C’$$